# Got an error 'non-numeric argument to mathematical function' from for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm dealing with some simple R code with for loop.
The main objective of my code is to calculate chi-square value with given data sets(matrices) with for loop

I have 2 matrices with dimension 5*15 (B and d)
Following pictures are  matrix B, matrix d respectively.

```
free<-matrix(NA,nrow=15,ncol=5)

for(i in 1:5){
for(j in 1:15){
    free[i,j]<-chisq(i,j)
   }
 }


chisq <-function(i,j){ 
pchisq(B[i,j],df=d[i,j],lower.tail=FALSE)
}
```

matrix B:

[image: Screenshot 1]

matrix d:

[image: Screenshot 2]

And finally, the error of the result from the code is

```
Non-numeric argument to mathematical function.
```

Could you please help me to find out what's the problem(s)?

It would be great to know how to fix it.

---

With your help, I edited my code like this

```
B<-as.matrix(B)
d<-as.matrix(d)
free<-matrix(NA,nrow=15,ncol=5)

chisq <-function(i,j){
      pchisq(B[i,j],df=d[i,j],lower.tail=FALSE)
      }

for(i in 1:5){
        for(j in 1:15){
        free[i,j]<-chisq(i,j)
      }
    }
```

Then the error message is

```
Error in B[i, j] : subscript out of bounds
```

---

following the comment to post dput(d) and dput(B) 
I've got this!

> dput(d)
>       structure(c(12, 23, 18, 14, 12, 20, 12, 15, 17, 16, 24, 19, 14, 
>       13, 16, 12, 22, 16, 13, 12, 17, 12, 13, 17, 13, 23, 17, 13, 13, 
>       12, 11, 22, 15, 13, 12, 16, 12, 13, 15, 13, 23, 16, 11, 12, 11, 
>       11, 22, 14, 13, 12, 16, 12, 12, 14, 11, 22, 14, 11, 12, 10, 11, 
>       22, 14, 13, 11, 16, 10, 12, 14, 11, 21, 14, 10, 10, 10), .Dim = c(15L, 
>       5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5")))
>   dput(B)
>       structure(c(63.4359, 161.77, 104.931, 42.9404, 18.3315, 51.2222, 
>       22.0478, 72.04, 89.8262, 45.0258, 137.835, 74.5486, 65661.7, 
>       51.2519, 57.2574, 63.4359, 135.564, 96.5449, 42.7049, 18.3315, 
>       47.9553, 22.0478, 65.6375, 89.8262, 26.9698, 121.79, 69.53, 66.8152, 
>       51.2519, 52.6687, 61.041, 135.564, 95.4561, 42.7049, 18.3315, 
>       42.9336, 22.0478, 65.6375, 88.567, 26.9698, 121.79, 67.9544, 
>       65.0612, 49.9536, 52.0815, 61.041, 135.564, 95.138, 42.7049, 
>       18.3315, 42.9336, 22.0478, 65.3476, 88.567, 22.2159, 119.689, 
>       41.1733, 65.0612, 49.9536, 51.6908, 61.041, 135.564, 95.138, 
>       42.7049, 16.0557, 42.9336, 20.369, 65.3476, 88.567, 22.2159, 
>       118.65, 41.1733, 59.8942, 39.9696, 51.6908), .Dim = c(15L, 5L
>       ), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5")))

Comment: Welcome to SO! Make sure your matrices are actually numeric. Check if the numbers are not character class for some import reason.

Comment: Thanks for  your comment! But as you see, the class of elements in matrix B are double and d are integer. Are they reasons for the error?

Comment: It is hard to tell, without a working example. The definition of `chisq` follows it's use. That is strange. Are you shure, that the function `chisq` that is in your namespace is the one, you're showing us? How is `free` initialized? Don't check types of variables with `View`, use `str`. Again: Please write a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Bernhard The chisq is my own function and the free was defined free<-matrix(NA,nrow=15,ncol=5) I've got this message in R 
str(B) Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 15 obs. of 5 variables: str(d) Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 15 obs. of  5 variables:
And I'm sorry for your request that I cannot write a reproducible example since my reputation is too low to do that (If you are talking about data)
Newbie is struggling to edit her question now :(

Comment: it looks like you have your dimensions switched?  `B[i,j]` tries to select the element from the ith *row* and the jth *column* ?

Comment: Thank you for the comment @BenBolker You're right. I want to save results from for-loop into the new matrix 'free' I defined below

Comment: Post the results of `dput(d)` and `dput(B)` so we can reproduce your error

Comment: Thank you for your comment @csgroen I'll attach the result in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
for(i in 1:15){
  for(j in 1:5){
    free[i, j]<-chisq(i,j)
  }
}
```

i. e. `i` is the row und runs from 1 to 15 und `j` is the column and runs from 1 to 5.

even better: use speaking variable names as in

free<-matrix(NA,nrow=15, ncol=5)

```
for(row in 1:15){
  for(col in 1:5){
    free[row, col]<-chisq(row, col)
  }
}
```

Makes thins kind of error more easily visible.

Comment: I really appreciate with your help! :D I've got the right results from the loop... Silly me :( The former error messages in the question seems to happened for the wrong data structure. (i.e. data.frame rather than matrix) Still, I don't know why it has happened because I clicked the button 'import data set from csv' 
I also will use row and col rather than i and j in loops as you wrote. That is a brilliant way to clarify codes for someone like me :)
Anyway, many thanks for your big help! 
with warm hug, Ellie